# ng2-pdfjs-viewer: PDF is all black

Tags: pdf, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I have a Problem with ng2-pdfjs-viewer.
Sometimes the PDF I try to display is all black.
I figured out, that it appears to be black whenever the PDf was created with j&k DPU-X.
If the PDF was created by OmniPage CSDK 19 it works just fine.
So the Problem is, that I acquire the PDF by REST call and that the exact same PDF appears sometimes to be created with j&k DPU-X and on another call with OmniPage CSDK 19.
I also see, that the one which is all black is way smaller despite the Byte[] I use is the same
for both cases.
Is there any possibility to change these information or how are they determined?

[image: Console log for both cases]

[image: Document details for the black one]

[image: Document details for the working one]

Thank you for you help and input.

Comment: You have two entirely different PDF files, as you noted. The Producer strings you're seeing are metadata contained in the PDF files and generally meaningless to the display. It's likely that the JavaScript PDF viewer is simply not able to display the PDF that's rendered black. I'd suggest you compare the files using desktop software & find out if there is a bug/non-compliance with the JavaScript library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to be following your suggestion and check the files and the JavaScript library.